# ASP.Net MVC personal account with Windows authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please tell me, there is an Asp Net MVC project with windows authorization. That is, it will only work within the local network. Implemented connection to AD and displaying all users on a table in the form of a telephone directory. Also in the project there is a definition of who is authorized. And so the question is, how can you implement a personal account for each user. For example for storing photos. I know that in AD you can store photos in attributes. But I wanted more than 2 photos. or storing additional information missing in AD. How to make this whole thing friends with MS SQL (will you have to store additional information there?)

```
HomeController

    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult GridViewPartial()
    {
        IEnumerable<Person> persons = GetPeople();
        return PartialView("_GridViewPartial", persons);
    }
    public static List<Person> GetPeople()
    {

        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

        var path = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Domain", "OU=Domain, DC=Domain, DC=Domain");

        UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(path);
        user.Enabled = true;


        user.Name = "*";
        //user.VoiceTelephoneNumber = "*";
        user.EmailAddress = "*";
        //user.Description = "";
        var search = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher();
        search.QueryFilter = user;
        var results = search.FindAll();
        foreach (UserPrincipal item in results)
        {
            var directoryEntry = item.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

            people.Add(new Person
            {
                DisplayName = item.Name,
                PhoneNumber = item.VoiceTelephoneNumber,
                ExtensionPhoneNumber = item.VoiceTelephoneNumber,
                Email = item.EmailAddress,
                Office = directoryEntry.Properties["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"].Value as string,
                Department = directoryEntry.Properties["subdivision"].Value as string,
                Title = directoryEntry.Properties["title"].Value as string,
                DepartmentNumber = Convert.ToInt32(directoryEntry.Properties["departmentNumber"].Value),
                Subdivision = directoryEntry.Properties["department"].Value as string,
                Manager = directoryEntry.Properties["manager"].Value as string,
                Mobile = directoryEntry.Properties["mobile"].Value as string,
                EmployeeNumber = Convert.ToInt32(directoryEntry.Properties["employeeNumber"].Value),
                company = directoryEntry.Properties["company"].Value as string,
                BirthDay = Convert.ToDateTime(directoryEntry.Properties["postOfficeBox"].Value)
            });
        }
        return people;
    }
    public static string GetProperty(Principal principal, string property)
    {
        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
        if (directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(property))
            return directoryEntry.Properties[property].Value.ToString();
        else
            return String.Empty;
    }

    public PartialViewResult Details(string name)
    {
        Person person = GetPeople()
            .Find(x => x.DisplayName == name);
        return PartialView(person);
    }
```

model

```
public class Person
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Office { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string ExtensionPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentNumber { get; set; }
    public string Subdivision { get; set; }
    public string Manager { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
}
```

Separation of access rights based on security groups
[security groups](https://www.benramey.com/2014/10/20/active-directory-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-5-with-forms-authentication-and-group-based-authorization/)

Comment: Mostly yes. Post what you have tried, and where you are getting stuck in implementing this, we will try to help.

Comment: Look, I made a change. 
Authorization only not forms

Comment: @mxmissile, 
I made changes

Comment: Where exactly in your code is it not working?

Comment: @mxmissile, The code works, but I do not know how to create a personal account for the user with the addition of additional information that is not in AD. For example: About me, photo, vacation date.

Comment: @mxmissile, found where the code doesn't work.
` public PartialViewResult Details(string name)
    {
        Person person = GetPeople()
            .Find(x => x.DisplayName == name);
        return PartialView(person);
    }
`
I get the current logged in user with User.Identity.Name. How do I pass it to the name variable?